# Genus computation

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

What is the smartest way to compute the genus of a hyperelliptic curve $C: y^2 = f(x)$ (with $f$ a separable polynomial of degree $n> 3$ over a field $k = \bar{k}$ of characteristic $0$ (prob. characteristic unequal $2$ is enough). (Just to be precise, I am referring to the unique nonsingular curve proper over $k$ defined by this equation.)

There are two ways I can think of, but neither is very clean. I'm wondering if this can (or cannot?) be avoided.

$\textbf{More detail:}$

We have the equation $z^{n-2}y^2 = z^n f(x/z) \subset \mathbb{P}^2$. Just to be precise, let's call this singular planar model of $C$ by $D$. The rational map from $\phi: \mathbb{P}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{P}^1:  (x,y,z) \mapsto (x,z)$ is of degree $2$ on $D$, and well-defined on the curve $D$ (except at the point $(x,y,z) = (0,1,0)$). Computing the ramification (outside this point, which is the unique singular point of $D$) is trivial, the entire issue is really just to determine the ramification at the (blow-up) of this point.

Note that the image of $\phi|_D$ is the complement of the point $(1,0) \in \mathbb{P}^1$.

$\textbf{Method 1}$: We can blow up the unique singular point $(0,1,0) \in D$ enough times, find the number of points of the strict transform, and that settles the issue. Even if the degree of $f$, $n$ is $6$ this seems like a lot of work!

$\textbf{Method 2}$: Let $P = (0,1,0)$. Then, compute the invariant $\delta_P$, where $\delta_P = \textrm{length}( \tilde{\mathcal{O}}_{D,P}/ \mathcal{O}_{D,P})$. Then, $p_a(D) - \delta_P(D) = p_a(C)$. It's of course easy to compute the arithmetic genus $p_a$ of $D$, since this we can change to a non singular element of the relevant linear system, and then compute the genus of a ns planar curve. But, is it easy to compute $\delta_P$?

What's the easiest way to compute the genus?

Answer (score 9):

I would use the double cover $C\to \mathbb P^1$ induced by the rational function $x$ and compute the genus with Riemann-Hurwitz as you do.

Over the finite part $\mathrm{Spec} k[x]$, the cover is given by $k[x][y]/(y^2-f(x))$. Over the part containning $x=+\infty$, the cover is given by $k[1/x][y/x^d]$, where $d=[(\deg f+1)/2]$, with the equation  $$(\frac{y}{x^d})^2=\frac{f(x)}{x^{2d}}\in k[1/x].$$

Comment: topologically think of the complex plane plus a point at infinity as a sphere.  then cut slits between successive pairs of zeroes of f, obtaining [n/2] slits (if n is odd cut one from the last zero to the point at infinity].  Then the branched double cover represented by the curve is obtained by joining two copies of such spheres along the edges of their corresponding slits.  This gives a topological surface with [n/2] tubes, i.e. [n/2 - 1] holes.  so the genus is [n/2 -1].

Comment: Thanks for your comment Roy!, I'm still thinking about it :) @Qing, Thanks! I didn't think one could make this all so explicit, so succinctly.

Comment: @Roy, Nice argument! I hate to ask, but why is the branched double cover represented by the (singular) curve obtained in this way? I would be very happy if you could give me a reference, so I can learn this point of view.

Comment: I think he only wants to be changing by $x^{d/2}$, so that the curve is nonsingular.

Comment: LMN, you are apparently asking for the genus of the normalization of the singular plane curve, i.e. analytically that is the genus of the unique riemann surface that maps birationally onto the singular curve.  The construction given does that.  does that answer the question?

Comment: Rick Miranda's book is quite wonderfully clear on algebraic curves from the perspective of their associated riemann surfaces.  I also have class notes i could send wherever you wish.  the basic statement is there is a functor from irreducible plane curves and rational maps, to riemann surfaces and holomorphic maps.  each algebraic curve is equipped with a surjective holomorphic map of degree one from its riemann surface, and each rational map between algebraic curves gives rise to a holomorphic map of riemann surfaces making the corresponding diagram commute wherever defined.

Comment: Roy, do you know if I would be able to extract this (that is, compute the genus of the non-singular model of arbitrary reduced & irreducible plane curves over the complex numbers) from Griffiths-Harris or one of Claire Voisin's books Hodge Theory books (possibly by working a little harder).

Comment: @roy smith: By "rational map", in the previous comment, you actually mean "regular map", right? Under the algebraic/analytic correspondence regular goes to holomorphic and rational goes to meromorphic.

Comment: @Qfwfq:  Hi!  You are of course correct.  The field of rational functions on an irreducible plane curve is isomorphic to the field of meromorphic functions on its associated compact connected riemann surface, and every rational map between two irreducible plane curves yields a meromorphic map between their riemann surfaces.  But in dimension one a beautiful thing happens: every meromorphic map between two compact riemann surfaces extends to a unique holomorphic map.  (Exercise: a map to P^n defined by meromorphic functions (f0,...,fn) on a disc, extends to a unique holomorphic map.)

Comment: as to Griffiths and Harris, the computation of the genus of a hyperelliptic plane curve of the sort mentioned in your question is done on pages 254-5 of my copy, by explicitly computing a basis of one forms.  The genus of a smooth plane curve of degree d is also given on pages 219-221.  I do not think they treat more general singular plane curves.  Of course since they give the Hurwitz formula, the genus is immediate from the double cover of the x axis as explained in answers here.  I would guess Voisin's book is more abstract, but do not have it at hand.

Comment: you are welcome.  of course i meant in the last comment that the pole set for the functions f0,...,fn was only at the origin.

Comment: @roy smith: you're right, yet calling those "rational maps" felt a bit strange to me :)  (except in the case of morphisms $X\to\mathbb{P}^1$, in which case we can aptly call them rational *functions*! ). 

Comment: Qfwfq: i apologize for my carelessness. the reason i call them rational maps between irreducible projective curves is that they are defined by rational functions, and also they are not regular everywhere unless the domain curve is smooth. e.g. the inverse of the rational parametrization of a cuspidal cubic curve taking t to (t^2,t^3), is a rational map taking (x,y) to y/x, is not regular at (0,0), but it induces a regular map on riemann surfaces. in particular every birational map of not nec. isomorphic irreducible plane curves induces an isomorphism of riemann surfaces.  but you know this. 

Comment: perhaps it helps to remove analysis from the discussion. if we think about normalization, then for reduced irreducible (possibly singular) projective curves, normalization is a functor that takes rational maps, perhaps not everywhere defined, to regular maps, defined everywhere.  there are 3 special characteristics of the phenomenon that rational maps are regular: smoothness, completeness, and dimension one.  it fails without all of these holding.

Answer (score 3):

It is easy to compute the ramification at that point, because of a general fact about covers of degree $2$.  Each point is either ramified ($e_p=1$) or unramified, and the the total number of ramified points is even.

Probably the easiest way to see this is from Riemann-Hurwitz, which I presume you're already using to compute the genus. If there are an odd number of ramification points, the formula for the genus that you get is not a whole number!

Thus, if $n$ is odd, the point at $\infty$ is ramified in the blowup. If $n$ is even, it is unramified. So $g$ is the ceiling of $n/2-1$.

This  should work in odd characteristic as well.

In characteristic $0$, you can also prove it by computing the fundamental group of $\mathbb P^1 $ minus $n$ points.